# How to get the number of timers in a process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer, ulimit

I'm having exactly the same problem described here:

[timer_create() : -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179427/timer-create-1-eagain-resource-temporarily-unavailable)

in short, some process is reserving a lot of timers via timer_create but never release them.
What I cannot figure out is how to determine the process affected by the leak in our production environment.

How could I know what process is the bad one, without randomly killing all the running stuff?

Any */proc/`pidof myprocess`/* debug info that tell me how many timers are reserved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you figured out how to find out which process is consuming all the timer resources?

Answer (score 2):

Why yes, actually. Use the [`stap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stap) tool to trace system calls and determine which calls processes make most often.

The [SystemTap Beginners Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide) is a good resource. In particular, see the script on [this page](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/timeoutssect.html) for an example of counting specific system calls per process.

Comment: Even if not exactly what i was looking for this tool looks fantastic, and it will help for sure! Thank you!